# Trying to create a program using linked list for character counting?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program that is a character counter using 
  a linked list and I am struggling. I have to program this in C#. If anyone can see a solution please tell me. I am have troubling using a linked list with nodes trying to show the results of counting characters. What am I missing? What do I need to add? By the way I am using visual works to run my code.

(First file)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp17
{
    class CharacterFrequency
    {
        private char ch;
        private int frequency;

        public char Ch
        {
            get { return ch; }
            set { ch = value; }
        }
        public int Frequency
        {
            get { return frequency; }
            set { frequency = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

(Second file)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp17
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int ch;

            const int InputFile = 0;
            const int OutputFile = 1;
            StreamReader reader = null;
            StreamWriter writer = null;
            //Declaring Linked List
            CharacterFrequency obj = new CharacterFrequency();
            LinkedList list = new LinkedList<CharacterFrequency>();

            //To read the characters in the Input File.
            reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(args[InputFile]));
            //To insert text through the loop.
            while ((ch = reader.Read()) != -1)
            {
                //Creating my linked list.
                CharacterFrequency cf = LinkedList<CharacterFrequency>
                list(ch);
                //Creating my nodes.
                LinkedListNode<CharacterFrequency> node;
                node = list.Find(cf);
                //Conditions
                if (node != null)
                {
                    node.Value.Add(cf, 1); //Increase in increments.
                }
                else
                {
                    list.AddLast(cf); //If it is not on the list yet, add it.
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            //Create my output file.
            writer = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(args[OutputFile]));
            //Display on prompt.
            foreach (CharacterFrequency cf in list)
                writer.WriteLine(cf.ToString());
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give us an example input and output?

Comment: Why do you want a linked list, just use a dictionary

Comment: For example, “Character” would be appropriate for C#/VB. Continued on the next page CharacterFrequency -ch : char -frequency : int +getCharacter() : char +setCharacter(character : char) +getFrequency() : int +setFrequency(frequency : int) +increment() +Equals() :

Comment: Because I was asked to create a program using a linked list

Comment: It's good practice to use `using { }` for IDisposable objects like Streams. Regarding app, You should code it by yourself to learn.